# Galssfish install on CentOS not binding ipv4 port

Tags: linux, glassfish

After installing Glassfish on a CentOS only unziping the zip archive, my server doesn't not bind on ipv4.

With

```
netstat -tnlup
```

I've got the result :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5278/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4621/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4825/master         
tcp        0      0 :::8686                     :::*                        LISTEN      14659/java          
tcp        0      0 :::4848                     :::*                        LISTEN      14659/java          
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      14659/java          
tcp        0      0 :::3700                     :::*                        LISTEN      14659/java          
tcp        0      0 :::8181                     :::*                        LISTEN      14659/java          
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      4621/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      4825/master         
tcp        0      0 :::7676                     :::*                        LISTEN      14659/java          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               1168/dhclient
```

How can I force glassfish listen on ipv4 addresses too ?

Answer (score 0):

You may find Glassfish is bound to IPv4 (and IPv6) but is being blocked by the iptables firewall settings:

As root:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Then try accessing Glassfish via IPv4. If that works then you can re-enable iptables and set the appropriate rules for your environment.

That CentOS isn't showing ports bound on IPv4 when they are also bound on IPv6 looks like a bug to me (2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem.  Not sure yet what triggered the issue, as I have two other servers with the same software that don't show this issue.

In my case, I was able to fix it by adding this environment variable:
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Once I restarted Java with this variable, it bound to IPv4, but not v6.  I'm curious as to why it's not binding to both.

Comment: Apparently this isn't necessary.  Java binds to IPv6, but it should be reachable via both stacks.